# Reading specific keywords from a file using set and map in Java

Tags: java, file, dictionary, set

I created a file that contains a text. I want to read specific words like "end", "so", and "because" using `set` to store these keywords and using `map` to display all the keywords and the number of times repeated. Can you show me how I should go about doing that?

EDITED

This is my draft:

```
openButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(); 
        int chosenFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if(chosenFile == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){ 
            File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile(); 
            String extension = getExtension(selectedFile.getName()); 
            if ( selectedFile.canRead()) 
                Set<String> keywordList = new HashSet<String>();k
                keywordList.add("and"); 
                keywordList.add("so"); 
                keywordList.add("because”);
```

I don’t know how I can go from here to use map to fine the keyword

Comment: is not there a start point yet? can you at least provide a scratch of the code that you are planning to use?

Comment: I created a user interface with a button find the file and select it and a textArea to display the results.

Comment: I created a GUI with a button to select the file and a TextArea to display the results. 
openButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

Answer (score 2):

I aggree to emecas....please provide some code...this is not a place where ready made code is available to you...

here is pseudocode for your use..

```
Loop through each line of file (use Scanner)
{
    Split current line using space as delimeter and make array ( Use String.split function)
    Loop through each word of array  
    {
        See if word is in Set( using contains method of set)
        If in set
        {
            see if word is in map (use map.get method)
            if present
            {
                put <word,1> in map
            }
            else
            {
                use get method to get current cound of word from map.
                Increment by one.
                put <word,incremented count> in map
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: openButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
          
int chosenFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
if (chosenFile == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {           
File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
String extension = getExtension(selectedFile.getName());
if ( selectedFile.canRead()) 

Set<String> keywordList = new HashSet<String>();keywordList.add("and");
   keywordList.add("so");
   keywordList.add("because”);
don’t know how I can go from here to use map to fine the keyword

Comment: I can't post the code in a nice way because the website won't let me

Comment: @Marocain Yeah you can.  You just can't do it in comments.  Instead you should edit your question.  Someone has already done that for you.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this website. thanks for the tip.